# rbconfig setup for rspec in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rspec

After setting up rspec in windows. I receive the following message;

```
C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/
C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/rspec-core/ruby/1.9.1/gems/autotest-4.3.2/lib
/autotest.rb:77: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
```

How do I switch to RbConfig in the windows environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning occurs in the `autotest` gem, which is third-party to your app: it uses the `Config` class rather than `RbConfig`.
You can either:

- simply ignore it,
- try to upgrade to a [more recent version of `autotest`](https://rubygems.org/gems/autotest/versions) to see if this warning disappears, and if not, maybe open a ticket for the `autotest` project.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer couldn't have been more simple.  I just went to line 77 in autotest.rb as the message suggests and change config to RbConfig.

On to the next error!

Comment: Right, but next time you install it again, or change environment, it’ll be back. (=